# Trying to connect a winforms app with a web Portal, where a login is required

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-to-web

How can I have the user connect from winform to the web portal using the login and password?  I tried with  `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Url, user, password, domain)` but it doesn't work.  I thought to use `WebClient` but I don’t need either upload or download for any file to the Portal, is just to navigate inside the Portal, I don’t know if that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right you want to get content of a page witch has authetication.

you can use webbrowser control.

```
//Navigate to page
webcontrol.Navigate("link");

//On document complete EVENT
//Send parameters and virtually click on login button
webcontrol.Document.GetElementById("UserName").SetAttribute("value", "username")
webcontrol.Document.GetElementById("Password").SetAttribute("value", "pass");
webcontrol.Document.GetElementById("LoginButton").InvokeMember("Click");

//Get loaded page
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoument.LoadHtml(webcontrol.DocumentText);
```

Comment: if I use WebBrowser control I should have it in my form and I don't want to do that, Really I dont know if that is correct or not, I said this because I tried putting the webbrowser control into another form and call that form when somebody click on the button, that handle that event, but I would need to pass the Url, user and password, from the form that contain the button to the form that contain the webbrowser control and when I did that I can't see anything in the webbrowser control, I mean, when I click on the button, the form with the webbrowser control is opened but with nothing on it.

Comment: @Eagle you can define the webcontrol as object without displaying it on the form and by this MatejKr answer will still be valid